# Custom headers - RunningText bug?

Tags: customization, printing, headers-footers

I'm trying to get MMA ready for writing papers and I'm almost there.
At first it looked like there was plenty of space for customization with custom headers and footers, but then it turned out that I can't use the RunningText feature through interface, because it's giving me a yellow cell with label "<< Running Text >>" instead of actual content. Bug?

So I've started searching the forum and found this:
[Change Header By Page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39645/change-header-by-page/39661#39661)
It *almost* works, few issues:

- No content parameter displays the parenthesis around the text (for example I'll pass an empty string "" and it displays "" instead of just blank space)
- I can't change the style of the running text no matter what I do, it's inherited from the cell style

You can check it by running the code from [Change Header By Page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39645/change-header-by-page/39661#39661)

I'm using Mathematica 10.1

Comment: Hi @Ranza , I'm not quite sure what you mean by your 1st issue, could you add a concrete and minimal example? About the 2nd issue, I think you can add any style you like in the corresponding "RunningText" cell directly.

Comment: Added an example to issue 1
Issue 2 - well I wanted to have Section names in the header, but not formatted as Sections because those use a large font. I'd like to get the cell content, but format it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround to the second issue:

Looks like using AuthorTools palette makes what RunningText does in a more primitive, but working way. It simply creates a list out of all cells of a certain style and plugs it to CounterFunction.