# Page Break Adjustment In Long Documents

Tags: front-end

Has anyone else had trouble in relocating page breaks in a long document? In a ~45 page long document I wanted to keep certain things on the same page. The system worked on the first three or four changes although it took a rather long time on each adjustment. On the next change the program seemed to lock up in a loop. The text on the screen vanished and the program was unresponsive. The CPU meter indicated MMA was working rather hard. I had to Alt F4 to get out. I repeated the problem twice.

Other than breaking the document into small pieces does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: This might be related with [the problems I reported here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/502/57) paginating one specific (rather short) file of mine. Paginating this file got mma hanging. It might have become corrupt or so. Did you try an unrelated file, but similarly long? What happens if you delete parts of your file and then paginate?

Comment: BTW Welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to do more on the site (post graphics, edit things, etc).