# How to create a dynamically self-updating table of content for a notebook?

Tags: dynamic, notebooks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a table of contents](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/476/generating-a-table-of-contents)

How to create a dynamically self-updating table of content for a notebook?  The TOC should contain the titles for the section, subsection, subsubsection etc. and should self-update as the new sections are added, and existing ones changed.  A "dynamic self-updating" part may be loosen from the question if it's too hard, i.e. a function that can be ran to generate a TOC which i can then manually copy.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/476/5

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but may be of some help: If you collapse the automatically formed cell groups of sections, or subsections, or whatever level you wish, then you already have an outline of the notebook which is just as good as a TOC. Just as good, that is, if you're viewing the notebook in Mathematica rather than reading a static pdf version or a printed version.

Comment: How to quickly collapse and un-collapse?