# Use of Mathematica to generate report

Tags: slideshows

I would like to generate a report for codes written in Mathematica, but I don't see basic features such as:

1. Table of Content generator
2. List of Figures
3. Abstract
4. Bibliography

and other standard report generators like LaTex?

Comment: Alas WRI abandoned interest in `AuthorTools` 6 years ago. The package is still bundled with Mma but has not been updated since V5.2

Comment: If you don't know by now I recommend to examine the standard  `Benchmarking` package. To open `MathematicaMark Report` go to `Help -> About Mathematica -> System Information -> Benchmark with MathematicaMark...`

Comment: Related question on ToC: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/476/5