# Why is Mathematica limiting the execution time of my calculation?

Tags: programming, front-end

Is there a Front End option (or programming option) in Mathematica 9 that limits the amount of time that functions take to execute?  I have a function (as part of a Mathematica Application) that shows page breaks and iterates though each cell of a notebook.  The function operated on large notebooks without problem in Mathematica 8, however in Mathematica 9, it reaches a different point of the notebook each time (and almost gets to the end if page breaks are already showing).  The function operates without problem on each half of the notebook (and on smaller notebooks). I have not used any TimeConstraint options.  Also note, that I am able to execute the function using  Workbench (with Mathematica 9).

**EDIT**
The function is to create a table of contents (a slightly modified version of the code given on [Stack Exchange: Generating a Table of Contents](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/476/generating-a-table-of-contents)).  It includes cells that are already tagged.

The code is executed via a button.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting `$HistoryLength`?

Comment: A bit more information on what your function actually does and how it is implemented would be very useful.

Comment: @Verbeia, Thanks for pointing out $HistoryLength. I did not know of that setting.  It was set at Infinity, however changing it to zero did not help

Comment: as you say that the code works if called from the workbench, how exactly are you calling this functions (shift-evaluate, button, ...)? So far (?) I don't know of any global time constraints for shift-evaluation and would be very surprised if such constraints would have been introduced, for other ways to call your code I wouldn't be surprised if some default behavior might have changed...

Comment: @AlbertRetey, the insertToc function is executed using a button

Comment: The fact that it's in a button is the entire question.  None of your code matters.  The question could be boiled down to "Why does `Button["wait", Pause[20]; Print["done"]]` not complete"?  The answer to which is that you should add the option `Method->"Queued"` as an option to the `Button`.

Comment: @JohnFultz, Thank-you. That fixed the problem.