# Hyperlinks not preserved when saving in PDF format in MMA V10

Tags: bugs, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

I usually create my course contracts in Mathematica and then save them in PDF format.  The notebooks include hyperlinks and these have transferred to PDF without problem over the last several versions of Mathematica (at lease 7, 8 an 9).  Is there something different that I need to do in version 10 in order to preserve hyperlinks?

I tried `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]`. But this only changed font sizes.

Comment: I think you should file a bug report at [wolfram support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback). I do see the same issue here on OS X. On a Mac, you can use the built-in TextEdit to add hyperlinks using `Apple`-`K`. That's perhaps a workaround: copy the Mathematica document as plain text and add the links in TextEdit.

Comment: I confirm this bug in v.10.0.0 under Win7 x64. `Export["test.pdf",Hyperlink["Wolfram Research, Inc.", "http://www.wolfram.com"]]` produces a file without the hyperlink while in v.8.0.4 it gives a file with the hyperlink.

Comment: Still broke in V10.1

Comment: It is still broken in v10.2 (Windows)

Comment: Anyone have any idea of a work around here?   Still not fixed....

Comment: The PDF export is still broken. I.E. If you create a document in MMA with links to other places in the same document, using MMA 9, if you export to PDF, these links are PRESERVED. Saving the document using MMA 10 does NOT preserve these links. Yes, they could be created manually in the PDF file, but it was functionality present in v. 9

Comment: @Ranza, what kind of answer are you looking for? It seems somewhat unlikely that anybody could solve this problem without at least partially re-implementing the internal PDF converter...

Comment: I thought that perhaps someone would come up with a workaround by specifying something like BoxRules for the PDF export (I'm not sure whether it's possible) or disguise internal links somehow so they are interpreted as external links which work currently.

Comment: A bounty certainly draws attention to the issue. I wish we could vote for bugs to be fixed.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this anymore in 10.4 (Windows).

Comment: Hyperlinks in notebooks saved as .pdf work again in Mathematica 11.0.0.0 (on OSX 10.11)

Comment: Works fine for me in 11.0 too.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0 on Ubuntu and have no problems when I manually export my notebooks PDFs or by running `Export["test.pdf",Hyperlink["Wolfram Research, Inc.", "http://www.wolfram.com"]]`.

Comment: Using 11.3.0.0. Still has this problem.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 12.1.