# Version 10.3 PDF export

Tags: export, pdf-format

Before I upgrade to Version 10.3, can anyone tell me if the issues with hyperlinks and PDF export have been solved?

Here is the original post and issue I am referring to.

Hyperlinks not preserved when saving in PDF format in MMA V10

[LINK](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57706/hyperlinks-not-preserved-when-saving-in-pdf-format-in-mma-v10)

Comment: Probably you could provide more information about the issue, links to the discussion if already present (duplicate?).

Comment: I still have issue with pdf export on Mac.  I got garbled pdfs but if I mess with page breaks in the option inspector I can get it to clear up.  Strange.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be fixed on 10.3 (at least at a trivial level) for macos

```
Export["test.pdf", Hyperlink["Wolfram Research, Inc.", "http://www.wolfram.com"]]
```

(* test.pdf *)

```
Run["Open test.pdf"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the link works

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: HI, not sure if this will get any attention since the question is closed...  The PDF export is still broken.  I.E.  If you create a document in MMA with links to other places in the same document,  using MMA 9,  if you export to PDF, these links are PRESERVED.  Saving the document using MMA 10 does NOT preserve these links.  Yes, they could be created manually in the PDF file,  but it was functionality present in v. 9