# Hyperlinks in plain text not preserved when saving in PDF format in Mathematica V13

Tags: pdf-format, printing, hyperlink

I have a notebook containing hyperlinks, but when I save it in pdf format (print to PDF) the hyperlinks are not blue and not clickable.

According to [Hyperlinks not preserved when saving in PDF format in MMA V10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57706/hyperlinks-not-preserved-when-saving-in-pdf-format-in-mma-v10) hyperlinks worked in version 7,8,9, did not work in version 10, but then worked again in version 11.

Now with version 13, the hyperlinks do not work, when I use [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com) which probably uses the latest version 13.x.

If I use my local installation of Matehamtica 13.0.0 on Fedora 36 does also not support hyperlinks in pdf, but this installation suffers from much worse problems regarding pdf support([Pdf export is heavily flawed for simplest possible notebook such as a=b+c](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282773/82534)).

Is there any workaround or fix for this problem?

Edit: My problem differs from [Hyperlinks not preserved when saving in PDF format in MMA V10](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57706/hyperlinks-not-preserved-when-saving-in-pdf-format-in-mma-v10), in the sense that I do not experience any problems with the `Hyperlink`-command. I only face this problem with the automatic hyperlink creation in plain text:

In the `.nb`-notebook: both hyperlinks are clickable and blue. (The first one is automatically created because an url appears in the plain text)
[image]

In the printed PDF only "Wolfram Research, Inc" generated with the `Hyperlink`-command is clickable. In the plain text nothing is blue or clickable:
[image]

How do I get hyperlinked urls in plaintext to work in the pdf export?

Comment: If you used `Hyperlink`, was the second argument wrapped in `URL`?  If not, that might explain the behavior you are seeing.  Otherwise, I did not experience any issues with exporting hyperlinks.

Comment: You are right the command `Hyperlink` works. But if I add a url such as `http://www.wolfram.com` as plain text. Then this automatically gets turned into a hyperlink within the .nb notebook, but when I save it as pdf, it is not hyperlinked in the PDF.

Comment: You should add the cell expression for that cell to this question.