# How do I count the TOTAL number of "Subsection" cells in a notebook externally?

Tags: notebooks, cells, counting

I can count the number of `"Subsection"` cells in a notebook by evaluating the following code at the BOTTOM of the notebook.

```
CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "Subsection"}]
```

It only counts `"Subsection"` cells above the cell which I evaluate, so you should put the code at the BOTTOM of the notebook so the count is not short.

I'm trying to capture this count externally from another notebook.  I can't figure out how to do this as the code above must be evaluated in a cell inside the notebook being counted. And must be at the bottom.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?  Or is there a more direct method?

---

**Updated Response to Suggestion Below**:  @Dan7geo I am running M10.3 on MACOS 10.12.  To illustrate why your second suggestion fails using a custom stylesheet, I created a simple notebook with 1 subsection cells and evaluated it using your code with no custom stylesheet.  It works.  However, if I apply a custom stylesheet it alters the result.  See gif below.

[image]

Below is one expression from my stylesheet, that is adding to the count. There are 4 of them...

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 CellFrame->{{0, 0}, {0, 1}},
 CellMargins->{{15, Inherited}, {8, 18}},
 StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab" -> "Subsection"},
 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 30},
 PageBreakBelow->False,
 CellFrameMargins->4,
 CellFrameColor->GrayLevel[0.7],
 LineSpacing->{1, 2},
 LanguageCategory->"NaturalLanguage",
 CounterIncrements->"Section",
 CounterAssignments->{{"Subsection", 0}, {"Subsubsection", 0}, {"Item", 0}, {"Subitem", 0}, {
   "Subsubitem", 0}, {"ItemNumbered", 0}, {"SubitemNumbered", 0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}},
 MenuSortingValue->1250,
 MenuCommandKey->"4",
 FontFamily->"Gill Sans",
 FontSize->28,
 FontColor->RGBColor[0.7612268253604944, 0.29576562142366675`, 0.08555733577477684]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Updated to work with custom stylesheets and when notebook history tracking is turned on)

You can execute the following to find the number of subsections in any notebook:

```
Count[First@NotebookGet@NotebookOpen@"Test.nb", Cell[_, "Subsection",___], Infinity]
```

(Replace "Test.nb" with the path to the notebook you wish to check)

To find the number of subsections in the current notebook, you can run this command anywhere (not necessarily at the end):

```
Count[First@NotebookGet@InputNotebook[], Cell[_, "Subsection",___], Infinity]
```

Note that this method returns the total number of subsections within the notebook as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Neither seems to work.  I added an update with a pic to illustrate your second suggestion failing.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Weird. It works on version 11.0 on Windows 10. I don't have a machine with OS X to test this on.

Comment: You could try executing NotebookGet@InputNotebook[] and visually inspect the structure of the output and then try modifying the pattern given to Count.

Comment: Man... ok... I will try this.  Thanks for the help.  At least windows people have a solution.  : )

Comment: Try turning off Notebook History tracking in preferences (advanced)

Comment: Nevermind. Use the modified code I just updated. It should work with Notebook History tracking enabled

Comment: It works on simple notebooks like above, however, it fails on notebooks that have more types of cells.  I think looking for patterns like this creates issues because "Subsection" must get repeated too many times.  I will search through some of the code to try and isolate the issue and give you an example.  From what I see, your code overstates the count whereas the code CurrentValue[{"CounterValue","Subsection"}], when evaluated inside the notebook, has the correct count.  I want access to that counter while outside the notebook if possible.  But I will try your technique.

Comment: CurrentValue[{"CounterValue","Subsection"}] gives only number of subsections upto the previous section. Whereas the method I posted gives the total number in the notebook. 

You can test this by creating a subsection then a section and another subsection. Your method returns 1 and mine gives 2.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I should have been more clear.  And...I discovered the issue.  If you apply a custom stylesheet to the notebook to alter the look, it messes with the result of your code giving a count that's too high.  However, if you use CurrentValue[{"CounterValue","Subsection"}] at the end of the notebook you get the correct result regardless of whether you use a custom stylesheet or not.  It appears that your code also parses through the Stylesheet looking for instances of "Subsection".  I'm not sure how to stop this from happening.

Comment: If you can let me know exactly which stylesheet you're applying, I'll try to make the pattern matcher more robust.

Comment: I posted a gif above illustrating the issue.  Strange that a stylesheet would do this.

Comment: This issue doesn't occur for any built-in stylesheets. I've never used any custom stylesheets before so I can't test it with any.

Comment: It's a custom stylesheet I built.  I counted the number of times "Subsection" occurs in the stylesheet.  It's 4!  So I will include the code for just one of these cells above.  All 4 look similar.

Comment: Can you check if the code works now after adding that [[1]]?

Comment: Wow!  Solved... thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! That was actually my first upvote on this site :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understood correctly this should do:

```
Length @ Cells[InputNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Subsection"]
```

Comment: Yes, this is petty straight forward now that I see it.