# How to generate a table of contents?

Tags: notebooks

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/476/generating-a-table-of-contents) is several years old and while the code still works I was wondering if there was any update from the community or Wolfram.  The online references still point to AuthorTools which seems to be deprecated(?).

Generating a ToC is a must have for me document wise - it's weird that it's not on the 'insert' menu.

Comment: I would also like to have a table of contents that lists all the functions defined in a notebook (and allows one to jump immediately to the function.)  That way, it would be much easier to maintain and improve code.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/AuthorTools/tutorial/MakeContents.html